# How to sync comic books from LMDE 2 to iPad mini

Tags: linux-mint, lmde, ios

I have LMDE 2 and I'm wondering if there is any practical way to sync my comic books over to my iPad Mini running iOS 9 so I can read them on YACReader or a similar app. I've messed around with ifuse and libimobiledevice but I can't get the iPad documents folder to mount. Any suggestions?

Also I'm taking this laptop/iPad with me on deployment so network-related options aren't viable.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was installing Virtual Box and installing Windows 7 within it. That way I can move my comics over to Windows and then sync them to my iPad that way.